# Как обновить данные на странице ajax + vue + vuex?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

Как правильно сделать добавление отзывов?
При сабмите формы хочу добавить отзыв, отобразить на странице и очистить поля в форме. Как это можно реализовать ?

Мой вариант: В beforeCreated получить все отзывы c сервера и отобразить их на странице.Создать массив в store и в него записывать данные, которые нужно отобразить после сабмита формы.Но тогда появляется проблема, данные в форме продолжают быть привязаны к массиву т.е. очистить поля  не получится. Как можно решить данную проблему ? Код моего варианта ниже:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      review: {
        userName: '',
        reviewText: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
        sendReview() {
          this.$store.dispatch('postReview', this.review)
        }
      },
      computed: {
        reviews() {
          return this.$store.getters.getReviews
        }
      },
      beforeCreate() {
        this.$store.dispatch('loadReviews')
      }
  }
  // vuex store
  import Vue from 'vue';

  export default {
    state: {
      reviews: []
    },
    getters: {
      getReviews(state) {
        return state.reviews
      }
    },
    mutations: {
      updateReviews(state, data) {
        state.reviews = data;
      },
      addNewReview(state, data) {
        state.reviews.push(data);
      },
    },
    actions: {
      loadReviews({
        commit
      }) {
        Vue.http.get('url.json')
          .then(res => {
            return res.json()
          })
          .then(data => {
            commit('updateReviews', data)
          })
      },
      postReview({
        commit
      }, payload) {
        Vue.http.post('url', payload)
          .then(() => {
            commit('addNewReview', payload)
          })
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<template>
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Отзывы</h1>
  <form 
   @submit.prevent="sendReview">
    <input 
     v-model="review.userName"
     type="text" 
     placeholder="Имя" >
    <textarea 
     v-model="review.reviewText"
     placeholder="Отзыв"
     cols="30" 
     rows="3">
    </textarea>
   <input 
    type="submit" >
  </form>
  <ul>
   <li v-for="item in reviews">
    <h2>{{item.userName}}</h2>
    <p>{{item.reviewText}}</p>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:
т.е. теперь данные не зависят от v-model

```js
class Review {
  constructor(user, text) {
    this.userName = user
    this.reviewText = text
  }
}

sendReview() {
  const review = {
    userName: this.review.userName,
    reviewText: this.review.reviewText
  }
  this.$store.dispatch('postReview', review)
    .then(() => {
      this.review.userName = '';
      this.review.reviewText = '';
    })
}
```